# Navbar for React Website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am learning react. I am trying to create a navbar and have my tabs open components as new pages using browser router. (When I click the navitems nothing is happening) I have website_header.js as:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="/">Logo</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href='/'>Home</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2} href='/Band'>Band</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={3} href='/Discography'>Discography</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={4} href='/Media'>Media</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={5} href='/Contact'>Contact</NavItem>
        </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Then App.js as:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch  } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './components/website_header';
import Home from './components/website_index';
import Band from './components/website_band';
import Discography from './components/website_discography';
import Media from './components/website_media';
import Contact from './components/website_contact';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
              <Route path='/Band' component={Band}/>
              <Route path='/Discography' component={Discography}/>
              <Route path='/Media' component={Media}/>
              <Route path='/Contact' component={Contact}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If I put just this it works:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';


class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar brand='React-Bootstrap'>
        <Nav>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href='/'>Home</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2} href='/Band'>Band</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={3} href='/Discography'>Discography</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={4} href='/Media'>Media</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={5} href='/Contact'>Contact</NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated I am very new to this.

Comment: Use `<Link>` from react router or add a listener to those NavItems and programatically navigate.

Comment: how do you add a listener?

Comment: Did any of the 2 answers below help you? If so, please consider up-voting them and/or marking the best as "accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as oklas suggested, or replace `<NavItem>` with `<li>` and `<Link>`:

For react-router v4:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Navbar brand='React-Bootstrap'>
      <Nav>
        <NavLink to='/'>Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/Band'>Band</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/Discography'>Discography</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/Media'>Media</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/Contact'>Contact</NavLink>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

and for v3 and below (you may add `activeClassName` prop for styling on the active route link):

```
render() {
  return (
    <Navbar brand='React-Bootstrap'>
      <Nav>
        <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/Band'>Band</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/Discography'>Discography</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/Media'>Media</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/Contact'>Contact</Link></li>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

Just make sure to import `NavLink` or `Link` respectively from `react-router`.

Comment: I have a question for this one. Why when I click the home link would it not reopen those components? Only when I first start it does home run the correct components

Comment: @DavidBrierton, if you are already on the selected "page" it will not reload/reopen that page. For example if you are on `/Media` and you click on the `Media` link, nothing will happen. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No say I select band and come back to home it does not reload the home

Comment: @DavidBrierton, by clicking the link or using the "back" button in your browser?

Comment: just clicking the link

Comment: @DavidBrierton, try the first snippet of my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

The react-bootstrap has no integration with react-router. Use react-router-bootstrap for that:

```js
import {LinkContainer} from 'react-router-bootstrap'

<LinkContainer to="/home">
  <NavItem eventKey={1}>Home</NavItem>
</LinkContainer>
```

Comment: inside all the navbar stuff? or get rid of all the navbar stuff?

Comment: Wrap each element which you need to be a link.